# Validar inputs vacíos y enviar formulario usando javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de validar un form y si este no está vacío enviar los datos. Hasta el momento he conseguido validar el campo vacío. Para ello en html tengo:

```
  <form name="formRecovery" method="POST" action="recovery.php">
    <div class="mb-4">
      <label class="form-label"></label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="correo" name="emailTxt">
    </div>
    <div class="text-center mt-4">
      <button class="btn btn-success w-100" name="recovery-pass" type="submit">resetear contraseña</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Y con javascript valido que no esté vacío y si no está vacío enviar el formulario.

```
  document.formRecovery.addEventListener('submit', validarForm);

    function validarForm(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const inputPass = document.getElementById("email").value
      const form = document.formRecovery;
      if (inputPass == "") {
        alert('campos vacios');
      } else {
        form.submit();
      }
    }
```

El caso es que valida que el formulario no esté vacío, pero al enviar los datos en php no recibo ningún dato. No entiendo bien cómo solucionarlo.

Comment: Puedes usar validación HTML, basta con agregar el [atributo `required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required) a cada campo que no desees que se envíe vacío: `<input type="email" ... required>`

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola! Veo que tu problema está en el `event.preventDefault();` en el método `validarForm()` que está bloqueando la ejecución del formulario, puedes intentar eliminando la línea y me cuentas.

O sino, puedes ensayar esta otra forma para enviar los datos del formulario usando `fetch()` y el método `FormData`:

```
const formData = new FormData(form);
  fetch('recovery.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
  });
```

Esto enviará todos los datos del formulario a `recovery.php` y podrás acceder a ellos desde PHP usando `$_POST['emailTxt']`.

Comment: gracias lo voy a probar